# How to style ticks in Observable HQ?

Tags: observablehq

[Chart with code and wrong data display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTXty.jpg)

I have a problem styling the x-axis of a simple line chart in Observable HQ so that it displays years. Currently, it only shows the years with decimal separators.

I have tried different styling options with plot.axisX but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tick format like so:

```
Plot.plot({
  x: {tickFormat: ""},
  marks: [
  ...
```